# How to Send JWT in Request Header when using Basic Authentication in Dash (Flask)

Tags: python, authentication, flask, jwt, plotly-dash

I am writing a Dash app that requires the user to login using Basic Authentication. The user credentials are then sent to the server in the request header with every request.

What I would rather happen is that a JWT is produced on the client-side and sent in the request header (replacing the basic auth credentials in the request header) as it is much more secure. However, I am having trouble working out how to replace the request authorization headers in Dash.

The flow would be:

1. User inputs their credentials;
2. Credentials are used on client-side to grab JWT;
3. JWT is sent in request header with each request.

To be precise, I am unsure how to carry out step 3 above in Dash.

I am currently using [dash-auth](https://dash.plotly.com/authentication) for my basic authentication, Python 3.9, Dash 2.0.0.

Comment: This is an important question. Also, how can the callback routes be protected properly too?